# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How can i fix `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` in here?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = 'j!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Just 4 Fun"))
    print('Im ready captain!')

@client.command
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

client.run('...')
```

Full error:

> client = commands.bot(command_prefix = 'j!')
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#bot) , capital `B`

Comment: I would also avoid changing the presence of the bot inside of the on_ready() event. `command_prefix = 'j!'
description = '''Discord Bot made by ...'''
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# Create the bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=command_prefix, activity=discord.Game(name="none of your business"), status=discord.Status.online, description=description, intents=intents)`

Answer (score -1):

You can change:

```
client = commands.bot(command_prefix = 'j!')
```

To :

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'j!')
```